# All columns are giving correct value except for "Quantity" - using MySQL WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql

First of all, here is the fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itpf7hqLV9aejFXfWF4kKH/0

I've been working to construct a single query to achieve a report format required by my client. I have a working query from my previous work but it's a long process and require me to insert data into multiple tables. I stumbled upon MySQL `WITH ROLLUP` function. With this I can reduce my process significantly and perform my tasks quicker.

I managed to construct this query:

```
SELECT divrank AS "No.",
Gsroup AS "Group",
tQty AS "Quantity",
wQty AS "Weight",
gsls AS "Gross RM",
disc AS "Disc",
nsls AS "Net Sales",
ROUND((nsls/tns)*100,2) AS "Total %",
ncst AS "Net Cost",
nsls-ncst AS "GP",
ROUND(((nsls-ncst)/nsls)*100,2) AS "Margin %" FROM
(SELECT divrank,IFNULL(gsgroup,"Total") AS "Gsroup",
t.tQty,t.wQty,t.gsls,t.disc,t.nsls,t.ncst,outletcode,salesperiod 
FROM
(SELECT outletcode,
IF(gsgroup="food",1,IF(gsgroup="non-food",2,
IF(gsgroup="softline",3,IF(gsgroup="hardline",4,
IF(gsgroup="WEIGHING GOODS",5,IF(gsgroup IS NOT NULL,"zz","Grand")))))) divrank,
gsgroup,salesperiod,
IF(hqdeptcode <> 99,qty,0) tQty,
IF(hqdeptcode=99,qtyw,0) wQty,
SUM(Grosssales) gsls,SUM(discamt) disc,SUM(NettSales) nsls,SUM(totalcost) ncst
FROM deptsales_rpt_2 
WHERE salesperiod="2015-01" 
AND outletcode="b1" AND gsgroup 
NOT IN ("","SERVICES & OTHERS") 
GROUP BY gsgroup WITH ROLLUP) t ORDER BY divrank) s
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT outletcode,salesperiod,SUM(nettsales) AS tns 
FROM deptsales_rpt_2 
WHERE outletcode="b1" AND salesperiod="2015-01" 
GROUP BY outletcode,salesperiod) ts 
ON s.outletcode=ts.outletcode AND s.salesperiod=ts.salesperiod;
```

Similar to what you'll see in the fiddle. I have compared the end result with my previous work and everything is returning the correct result. But if you see on the "Quantity" column, it just shows `0`.

[![result][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2vkg.png

Can anyone help me point out where I do wrong?

Ok, I figured out the problem. I should `SUM` both of these:

```
IF(hqdeptcode <> 99,qty,0) tQty,
IF(hqdeptcode=99,qtyw,0) wQty,
```

It should be:

```
SUM(IF(hqdeptcode <> 99,qty,0) tQty),
SUM(IF(hqdeptcode=99,qtyw,0) wQty),
```

Comment: Your query has a table deptsales_rpt_2 but your fiddle does not?

Comment: my bad @P.Salmon , I've pasted the wrong link. I've updated the link. Sorry

Comment: You're having columns in the list of the `SELECT`, that aren't either arguments to an aggregation function or listed in `GROUP BY`. Though older versions of MySQL or with certain configurations accepts that, this may give unexpected results and like that it is not clear what you're actually after. It's also just plain wrong in most other DBMS. So you should rework that query and fix that issue first.

Comment: You aren't summing qty in the s sub query you are setting it to 0

Comment: I was guessing the same thing @P.Salmon , when I remove the `IF(hqdeptcode <> 99,qty,0)` condition and put `sum(qty)` only, it will sum all group whereas I'm looking to exclude `WEIGHING GOODS` group out of the quantity total sum.

Comment: Thanks @stickybit. In fact I am using MySQL 4.1 still. Our company is migrating to MariaDB 10.3 but this particular db is still using 4.1. I have to hold my thought first when you said this is plainly wrong because I'm yet to test this in the long run but I've been checking each query and sub-query and so far the results came out OK. Nonetheless, I've only come up with this query in about an hour after i discovered `WITH ROLLUP` so more or less, I'm just experimenting whether this function can work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT divrank AS "No.",
Gsroup AS "Group",
tQty AS "Quantity",
wQty AS "Weight",
gsls AS "Gross RM",
disc AS "Disc",
nsls AS "Net Sales",
ROUND((nsls/tns)*100,2) AS "Total %",
ncst AS "Net Cost",
nsls-ncst AS "GP",
ROUND(((nsls-ncst)/nsls)*100,2) AS "Margin %" FROM
(SELECT divrank,IFNULL(gsgroup,"Total") AS "Gsroup",
t.tQty,t.wQty,t.gsls,t.disc,t.nsls,t.ncst,outletcode,salesperiod 
FROM
(SELECT outletcode,
IF(gsgroup="food",1,IF(gsgroup="non-food",2,
IF(gsgroup="softline",3,IF(gsgroup="hardline",4,
IF(gsgroup="WEIGHING GOODS",5,IF(gsgroup IS NOT NULL,"zz","Grand")))))) divrank,
gsgroup,salesperiod,
SUM(IF(hqdeptcode <> 99,qty,0) tQty),
SUM(IF(hqdeptcode=99,qtyw,0) wQty),
SUM(Grosssales) gsls,SUM(discamt) disc,SUM(NettSales) nsls,SUM(totalcost) ncst
FROM deptsales_rpt_2 
WHERE salesperiod="2015-01" 
AND outletcode="b1" AND gsgroup 
NOT IN ("","SERVICES & OTHERS") 
GROUP BY gsgroup WITH ROLLUP) t ORDER BY divrank) s
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT outletcode,salesperiod,SUM(nettsales) AS tns 
FROM deptsales_rpt_2 
WHERE outletcode="b1" AND salesperiod="2015-01" 
GROUP BY outletcode,salesperiod) ts 
ON s.outletcode=ts.outletcode AND s.salesperiod=ts.salesperiod;
```